# Can I use amp-video-container with amp-video in amp-story even if I am not using amp-carousel? What does amp-video-container do?

Tags: video, amp-html, amp-story

Is there detailed documentation on amp-video-container? I am trying to understand how I can use amp-video-container in amp-story to ensure my video is not cut off and viewable in full.

https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/video_carousels_with_amp-carousel/

```
  <div>
    <div class="amp-video-container">
      <amp-reach-player class="amp-video"
        data-embed-id="default"
        layout="responsive"
        width="560"
        height="315">
      </amp-reach-player>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also, do I need to include this script tag when using amp-video-container?

```
<script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the full video to be shown, you can use CSS:

```
amp-video video {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

In the code snippet you've provided, there is nothing special about `amp-video-container`; it is simply a CSS class name.  You do not need any additional scripts to use this CSS, and this is unrelated to `amp-carousel`.

Comment: I added object-fit: contain. The video still does not fill the entire page.

Comment: Why would a reference page list an "amp-video-container" class without showing the CSS? (https://xbyexample.appspot.com/advanced/video_carousels_with_amp-carousel/)

Comment: You can see all of the code, including the CSS, by viewing [that sample in the AMP by Example playground](https://xbyexample.appspot.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fxbyexample.appspot.com%2Fadvanced%2Fvideo_carousels_with_amp-carousel%2Fsource%2F) (accessed by clicking on the pencil icon in you the page you've linked).

Comment: thanks. I see .amp-video-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .amp-video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55%;
  }

Comment: even with this css, however, the video does not fill the screen.

Comment: It's not possible every in theory to both fill the entire screen and not crop part of the asset, unless (a) the browser window and the asset are the same size (which cannot be guaranteed since browsers have different chrome and devices are different), or (b) you stretch the asset (which yields an undesirable result).

Comment: If the asset is roughly the same size as the screen, the stretching won't be too bad, especially since each amp-story grid area appears to be limited to a max width of tablet?

Comment: To stretch the asset you can use `amp-video video { object-fit: fill; }`.  But, do know that this can be quite problematic regardless of the width restriction.  For example, consider an iPhone X using Safari vs an iPhone 5 using Chrome.  The aspect ratios are drastically different.